# Combining many individual precipitation shapefiles to show by year in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, precipitation

I have 10 years of each year precipitation in shapefiles and would like to combine them into one to show years in ArcMap layer.

Do I need to use the append or union ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question is most easily answered by taking your shapefiles and doing two tests:

- [Append](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000) them together and examine the result
- [Union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000s000000) them together and examine the result

If either or both tests cause an error or do not meet your requirements then, after reviewing their documentation, you will be in a position to ask a more focussed question.

If one does almost, but not quite, what you what you want, then that too will place you in a better position to ask a more focussed question to try and uncover a more suitable solution to meet your requirements.

I would expect precipitation data to most likely be points which would seem to rule Union out as an option.